# Prove that $\cos^{-1}(\frac{2}{\sqrt 7})+\tan^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt 3}{5}) = \frac{\pi}{3}$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, inverse-function

I started off by making two right angled triangles. One having an angle $\alpha$ such that $\cos \alpha = \frac{2}{\sqrt 7}$ and the other having an angle $\beta$ such that $\tan \beta = \frac{\sqrt 3}{5}$.
Now from here I must show that $\alpha + \beta = \frac{\pi}{3}$.

However I am unable to find a relation between these two triangles.

It would be appreciated if someone could help me with the proof or give some kind of hint.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The values of $\cos \alpha$ are different in your title and question. Same for your $\tan \beta$.

Comment: Hint: Use complex numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that$$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt 7} \right) = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2} \right)$$
So we have
$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2} \right) + \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{5} \right) = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{\sqrt3}{2} + \frac{\sqrt3}{5}}{1 - \frac{\sqrt3}{2} \cdot \frac{\sqrt3}{5}} \right) = \tan^{-1}(\sqrt 3) = \frac{\pi}{3}$$

Comment: Equivalently,  $(2+i\sqrt3)(5+i\sqrt3) = 7 (1 + i \sqrt3)$

Comment: Yes, then take $\arg$ on both sides.

Comment: @lhf A very lateral remark : your identity reminds us that $\mathbb Z[i \sqrt{3}]$ isn't a Unique Factorization Domain..